# How to detect just one keyboard stroke in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, keyboard

I am trying to write MATLAB code which detects left and right arrow of keyboard stroke. Below is the code I wrote.

```
Background = figure(1);
for i = 1:10
    key(i) = double(get(Background,'CurrentCharacter'));
end
```

But it shows me a message that the number of element is not matched.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Need more information.  What is the exact type of handle given by `Background`? We can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Sorry. I add a line about 'Background'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you called [`waitforbuttonpress`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitforbuttonpress.html) before? As long as no key has been pressed, `get(...,'CurrentCharacter')` will return an empty char array which double converts to `[]`. This is what very likely causes an "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." error when assigning it to `key(i)`.

Why do you actually call the function 10 times? You will get the same result each time so all values assigned to `key(i)` are equal. If you want to record 10 consecutive keystrokes, you are missing a `waitforbuttonpress` inside the loop.

Btw, I'm implicitly assuming that `Background` is a handle to the active figure. You haven't told us what it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wanted to distinguish the keystrokes between left and right arrow. `waitforbuttonpress` only returns whether there is a button click or not so that's the reason why I didn't use that function.

Comment: You need both, `waitforbuttonpress` will wait for the event to happen, *afterwards* use `get(...,'CurrentCharacter')` to know if it was left or right...

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thanks!